# Traverse all transitions in a state machine

Tags: code-coverage, transition, state-machine

I need some help in traversing all transitions in a state machine. (all-transitions is a coverage criteria)
I have a state machine and I want to cover all transitions with minimum number of paths from source to target/abort state.
ex: 
A->B
B->B
B->C
B->D
so paths are: A->B->B->C, A->B->D

Answer (score 0):

Just write some test code to invoke your state machine:

1. Two calls where you expect to end with state C.
2. Two calls where you expect to end with state D.

Your test code should verify the end state.